# MVC partial view, datepicker issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, datepicker, partial-views

I have a partial view only for datepicker (jquery UI datepicker). When I use the partial view in my page one time it works perfectly. But when I have multiple instances of datepicker partial view, they start to misbehave. For example If I change the date of second instance, the date is changed in first one. how to address this issue?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var pickerOpts = {
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: '/images/CalendarView.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: 90
    };

    $('.dtp').datepicker(pickerOpts);  
  });
</script>

@model DateTime

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date, Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new {@class="dtp" })
```

Any help / suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: where did you define above javascript code? In Partial View or in main page?

Comment: Hi, I defined it within the partial view itself.

Comment: It might be issue with class 'dtp' selector. Try with id '#' selector

Comment: Hi, that is where I am struck. even if I create 10 instances of partial view, the id of the textbox remains the same. Is there any way of assigning id to each instance of partial view? Then I think it may resolve.

Comment: Scripts should never be in partials. Place them in the main view or layout.

Comment: Hi Stephen, agreed, but how does it solve the problem. When I am changing date in datepicker2, the first datepicker is getting changed.

Comment: can you show the first picker also?  is the class the same on both of them?

Comment: Yes, matt. actually I have pasted the code of partial view above. And that is being repeteadly used in main page, whenever there is a need for a datepicker , i am using @Html.partial("DatePicker") etc.

Comment: If your using `@Html.Partial()` to keep adding controls for property `Date` then your generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) and duplicate `name` attributes so you wont be able to bind to your model on post back so its a little unclear exactly what your trying to do.